# SQL to Nhibernate criteria

Tags: sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have class ClassA mapped to table TableA. How to convert next sql to NHibernate criteria?

```
  SELECT DISTINCT t.Id, (Select COUNT(*) FROM TableA WHERE [Id] = t.Id)
  FROM TableA AS t
```

**Update 1:** TableA is a view indeed. It's for merging statistic from two tables. Id is not identity, just the field, sorry for ambiguity.

Comment: I have a few comments. First - this query seems to have a circular reference. Second - I don't think you should ever have to query `DISTINCT` on an ID column. Third - it looks like you're trying to get a count of the many side on a `one-to-many` relationship. If this is the case, why not just map the relationship on the object, and then you could do `MyObject.ChildItems.Count`

Comment: Thanks for response. Please, look through update 1.

Comment: Due to the correlated subquery and the distinct, it looks like that could be a horribly inefficient query. Have you considered writing is a group by on t.id instead?

Comment: Not yet, but it seems to be a good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-projection:

```
List results = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(ClassA))
    .SetProjection( Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add( Projections.RowCount() )
        .Add( Projections.GroupProperty("Id") ) )
    .List();
```

Or with Linq:

```
from a in session.Query<ClassA>
group a by a.Id into g
select new { g.Key, g.Count())
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Btw, when I add Restrictions.In for "Id" field the result is incorrect(3 elements instead of 20 in my case). What can cause such issue?